# Web Role configuation for EF connectionstring

Tags: azure-configuration

I hear a lot of people talking about storing EF connection string in Role configuration settings (.cscfg). 
EF connection string could only be stored as a plain string there as the "Connection String" option is for storage connection.

In my project EF, connection string cannot be a plain string. And putting more strings and combining it to make a proper connection string is not an option at the moment. More over if Microsoft wants us to use database connection string in configuration setting , why is it that there is no option for it in .cscfg?

Doesn't it prove that .cscfg is not a replacement for .config?